# Can I get a Google street view from a Google Maps using the API?

Tags: google-maps

I created a Google map with 100+ markers using the API V3. Could I get the street view for every marker by clicking on it (in another map or in the same one) or something similar (not using the yellow man)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a [Streetview API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/streetview/index.html) that you can make use of

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,%20-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&sensor=false
```